# Keydown event preventDefault not working on Windows Phone 8.1 IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

I have input text field that should allow only +/- decimal values. I use keydown event to check the key value and prevent incorrect values.
It works successfully on all browsers except for IE on windows phone

```
$('#input_Value').bind('keydown', function (e) {
   var allowedkeys = [8, 37, 39, 46];
   var position = $(this)[0].selectionStart;
   var newVal = $(this).val().slice(0, position) + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + $(this).val().slice(position);
   var regex = /^(\-)?(\d{1,3})?(\,)?(\d{1,3})?(\,)?(\d{1,3})?(\,)?(\d{1,3})?(\.)?(\d){0,10}$/i;

   if (newVal == "-" || allowedkeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1)
        return true;
   else if (!(regex.test(newVal) && parseFloat(newVal))) {
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
   }
}
```

How can i preventDefault on windows phone IE?

Comment: I think no matter what you try you can avoid this if the user type in the `Word Flow` way.